# Identifying words in Tkinter Text widget which are new/have been modified

Tags: python, tkinter

What is the best way to identify words which have been modified in a Tkinter Text widget?

Right now, I am checking for and flagging new text every time the user modifies the text:

```
text = Text(frame)
text.bind('<<Modified>>', check_for_edits)
text_before_user = text.get('1.0', END)

def check_for_edits(event=None):  
    flag = text.edit_modified()
    if flag:
        text_after_user = text.get('1.0', END)
        if text_after_user != text_before_user:
            find_differences(text_after_user, text_before_user)
    # Resets edit_modified
    text.edit_modified(False)
```

Is there a better way to do this that does not require examining the entire contents of the text widget?

Comment: do you really care about changes to _words_,  or to changes to any random sequences of characters? How big is the data you're dealing with?

Comment: Minimally, changes to words, though it would be nice to track any character changes. The data could be up to a million lines of text.

Comment: You're going to have people editing million-line text files? Yowza.

Comment: A million lines is the arbitrary limit set for the text, which is acting as a notebook. More realistically, I expect users to have a number of lines somewhere in the thousands, which will be searchable using tags.